# How to add consistent grid-gutter-width across multiple breakpoints in bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, gutter

I'm using the latest bootstrap and I'm not having luck adding a simple margin between items in a responsive grid. I have a simple grid that scales from 4 / 3 / 2 / 1 columns based on the col setting (col-lg / col-md / col-sm / col-xs)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <!-- put stuff in here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like a simple way to override the default style (or the less property directly) to get a simple margin between items w/ the above layout.

By default this stacks correctly but each item is directly next to one another. How can I achieve the gutter width required with the least amount of hacking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BS3, the "gutter" is created using padding, instead of margins so easiest way to create the look of a gutter is by using a container inside the `col-*`..

http://bootply.com/113815

See this article to understand the Bootstrap 3 gutter:

http://blog.codeply.com/2016/04/06/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works/

Comment: so did you use a custom build with a set grid-gutter-width of 10/20/30px ?

Comment: It's using the standard Bootstrap build which (I think) uses padding of 15px on each side of the col (30px gutter)